# Java Problems encoding UTF8

Tags: java

I think the easiest way to explain my problem is with a little example:

My string at the beginning is: `PÃ¢tes`, and the result should be: `Pâtes`. What I get as result is still `PÃ¢tes` How can I fix this?

Here the code:

```
private String encode(String string) {
    try { 
        byte ptext[] =string.getBytes("UTF8");
        string = new String(ptext, "UTF8");   
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }     
    return string;      
}
```

Comment: Did you check out the enconding on you eclipse workspace?

Comment: what you get is exactly what your code does....

Comment: Isn't it `UTF-8` rather than `UTF8`?

Comment: Do not understand why you thought doing that would cause the human-readable representation of the data to change.....

Comment: Why would it be different?  Can you please explain which process should change the characters?

Comment: A method like that does not make sense. Think of a `String` in Java as a sequence of characters without any encoding attached. If you want a character `â`, it has to be already in the String. Encodings only come into play, when you convert a String to bytes or the other way round.

Comment: I think your problem is that somewhere earlier in your program the string was read in with a latin1 or similar encoding when it was actually UTF-8. So the multi-byte â got stored as the UNICODE string equivalent to the string of octets each treated as a single character. Nothing inside the encoding system can fix this, you need to fix it earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.  The first is that you're using `UTF8`, but the correct character set is `UTF-8`.

The second is that you're essentially performing a no op.  By calling `byte ptext[] =string.getBytes("UTF-8");` you are saying that this string is UTF-8.  Then you convert it to UTF-8 which it already is.

What I think you mean is that the input is `ISO-8859-1` and you want to convert it to `UTF-8`.  (This fits with the example input and output you've given).

Try:

```
private String encode(String string) {
    try { 
        byte ptext[] = string.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
        string = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");   
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }     
    return string;      
}
```

This assumes that your initial string was originally read from somewhere and only contains `ISO-8859-1` characters.  As mentioned in a comment you should try to ensure the data is loaded in correctly from the source (i.e. when it is still just an array of bytes).

Comment: No, don't do that. Instead make sure that the string is correct in the first place. It has to come from somewhere, using the correct encoding there will do the trick.

Comment: @Henry good point.  I've added a note about that.  I think the answer is still valid given that we don't know where the original came from and it might not be feasible to encode it properly without using this way.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html lists `UTF8` under "Canonical Name for java.io API and java.lang API", so I don't think that's an issue.

Comment: thx, yes indeed to encode a utf-8 and to code it back to utf-8 doesn t make sense at all.

Comment: The string comes from a http Request. Initial stored in a database (UTF-8).